# VBA Macro - Export table data from Excel file to Word and create a section for each worksheet

Tags: excel, ms-word, worksheet, vba

I use a macro in VBA for exporting data coming from Excel into Word.

```
Sub ExportToWord()
    Set obj = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    obj.Visible = True
    Set newobj = obj.Documents.Add

    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
        ws.UsedRange.Copy
        newobj.ActiveWindow.Selection.PasteExcelTable False, False, False
        newobj.ActiveWindow.Selection.InsertBreak Type:=7
    Next
        newobj.ActiveWindow.Selection.TypeBackspace
        newobj.ActiveWindow.Selection.TypeBackspace

    obj.Activate
    newobj.SaveAs Filename:=Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\OLD\" & Split(ActiveWorkbook.Name, ".")(0)
End Sub
```

All data and table layout are retrieved in Word. The Procedure will copy usedRange of each Worksheet to Word and page break by each Worksheet.

**I would like to update this script by putting the name of the worksheet just before the copy/paste data for each worksheet.**

Could you tell me how to do that?

---

After updated the code:

```
Sub export_workbook_to_word()
    Dim sheetName As String
    Set obj = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    obj.Visible = True
    Set newobj = obj.Documents.Add

    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
        sheetName = ws.Name
        ws.UsedRange.Copy
        newobj.ActiveWindow.TypeText ws.Name
        newobj.ActiveWindow.Selection.PasteExcelTable False, False, False
        newobj.ActiveWindow.Selection.InsertBreak Type:=7

    Next
        newobj.ActiveWindow.Selection.TypeBackspace
        newobj.ActiveWindow.Selection.TypeBackspace

    obj.Activate
    newobj.SaveAs Filename:=Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & Split(ActiveWorkbook.Name, ".")(0)

End Sub
```

I obtain the error `Object doesn't support this property or method` on the line `newobj.ActiveWindow.TypeText ws.Name`

Could you please help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact The line

```
newobj.ActiveWindow.Selection.InsertBreak Type:=7
```

inserts a page break: 7 corresponds to wdPageBreak. I inserted a next page section break by changing 7 to 2 (corresponding to wdSectionBreakNextPage).

Sections in Word don't have names. I insert the name of the worksheet above the table:

```
    newobj.ActiveWindow.Selection.TypeText sheetName
    newobj.ActiveWindow.Selection.Style = ActiveDocument.Styles(-2)
    newobj.ActiveWindow.Selection.TypeParagraph
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to declarations:

```
    Dim sheetName as String
```

And this below the For Each statement

```
    sheetName = ws.Name
    newobj.ActiveWindow.TypeText (sheetName)
```

Comment: Hi,Thanks for the response but it doesn't work. I have the error "Invalid qualifier".

Comment: If `sheetName` is a `String`, then you will need to use `sheetName = ws.Name` instead of `sheetName.Text = ws.Name`.  (Or simply use `newobj.ActiveWindow.TypeText ws.Name`.)

Comment: I don't know where I have to put that. If I put that juste before the Next I obtain an error. Could you please help me?

Comment: Edited answer per YowE3K. What error do you get from newobj.ActiveWindow.TypeText ws.Name running in the For Each?

Comment: From MSDN, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/word-vba/articles/selection-typetext-method-word , the syntax for .TypeText is
 expression.TypeText (Text) so try newobj.ActiveWindow.TypeText (ws.Name) . Another example from that page is .TypeText Text:="Hello"